# Recursive query issues in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with a recursive query in SQL Server.

Suppose that I have 2 tables:

1. `Holiday`: this table stores all holidays (`holidayDate` which are not working day)
2. `Invoice`: this table stores the next payment date (`nextPaymentDate`)

If `nextPaymentDate` is on a  `holidayDate` in holiday table then I need to update it:

```
nextPaymentDate = nextPaymentDate + 1 day
```

This step needs to process until `nextPaymentDate` is not on a `holidayDate` anymore.

Please see the example of sample data below:

`Holiday` table:

```
HolidyaID      HolidayDate
-----------------------------
   1           2012-01-02
   2           2012-01-03
   3           2012-01-04
   4           2012-01-08
   5           2012-01-12
   6           2012-01-13
   7           2012-01-20
   8           2012-01-21
   9           2012-01-22
   10          2012-01-23
   11          2012-01-29
   12          2012-01-30
```

`Invoice` table

```
InvoiceID      NextPaymentDate
------------------------------
   1           2012-01-01
   2           2012-01-02
   3           2012-01-09
   4           2012-01-20
```

After running this query, I want to see the data in the `Invoice` table like this

```
InvoiceID      NextPaymentDate
-------------------------------
   1               2012-01-01
   2               2012-01-05
   3               2012-01-09
   4               2012-01-24
```

How could I create a SQL query to output this result?

You can test this query at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de346/3

Thank You!

Comment: What's recursive about this?

Comment: I think he is calling it recursive in need to hit Holiday until it finds an open date.   A cursor might be the way to go.

Comment: If you had a calendar table (one which contains one row for every day for the next 20 years isn't too difficult to build nor large), you could either a) just store a flag in there for holidays, and/or b) just find the `MIN(date)` from that table that is `>= NextPaymentDate` and which isn't a holiday.

Comment: aarolama-bluenk: It's like Blam said.

Answer (score 0):

```
select InvoiceID,
Case when [holidaydate] is null then [NextPaymnetDate]
else
DateAdd(dd,1,
(Select min([holidaydate]) from holiday h
where  h.[holidaydate]>[NextPaymnetDate]
and not exists(Select * from holiday h2 where h2.[holidaydate]=DateAdd(dd,1,h.[holidaydate])) 
))
end
from invoice
left Join holiday on [holidaydate]=[NextPaymnetDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with holidayBatch as
(
  select workingdate = dateadd(dd, 1, holidayDate)
  from Holiday h
  where not exists (select 1 from Holiday nxt
                    where nxt.holidaydate = dateadd(dd, 1, h.holidaydate))
)
select i.invoiceid,
  case when h.holidaydate is null then i.NextPaymentDate else hb.workingdate end
from Invoice i
  left join Holiday h on i.NextPaymentDate = h.holidaydate
  outer apply (select top 1 workingdate
              from holidayBatch hb where workingdate > NextPaymentDate
              order by workingdate) hb
order by i.invoiceid
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53db1/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select invoiceid, coalesce(nd,NextPaymnetDate) dd from invoice i left join
    (
    select *,(select min(dateADD(dd,1,holidaydate)) from holiday 
where holidaydate>=h.holidaydate and 
dateADD(dd,1,holidaydate) not in (select holidaydate from holiday)) nd 
    from holiday h) h on NextPaymnetDate = holidaydate;
```